# How do I get Kubernetes to work without the "connection over port 8080" error?

Tags: redhat, tcpip, kubernetes

I installed Kubernetes in RHEL 7.x.  I expect kubectl commands to work without errors. Port 8080 is not being blocked from my client workstation to the RedHat server with Kubernetes.  I tried several things to diagnose the problem.

I ran this command (to reproduce the problem): kubectl version

I saw this:

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7",
>   GitVersion:"v1.7.5",
>   GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-31T09:14:02Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} The
>   connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify
>   the right host or port?

The error about the port being refused is confusing me.

I ran this command:
nmap -p 8080 localhost

It shows that port 8080 is merely closed -- but not blocked.

I have no admin.conf file in /etc/kubernetes/.  Did I do something wrong?   How can I use kubectl commands without getting the error "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Every kubectl command I run returns this error.

How do I get the admin.conf file?  I was thinking of trying to install gcloud.  But "sudo yum install gcloud" did not work.  The package could not be found.  Maybe I don't need to bother with admin.conf or the gcloud utility.

How do I get kubectl commands to work without that error about the connection being refused on port 8080?

Answer (score 0):

8080 is the insecure port. meaning you don't need auth or ssl. If you want to enable port 8080 you need to run the apiserver with the following flag.

```
--insecure-port 8080
```